# Итератор поиска элементов коллекции

Tags: c#

Пришло время работы с интерфейсами и наступила проблема. Не понимаю как работает при определенном условии, Итератор для поиска элементов коллекции, удовлетворяющих заданному условию. Вот мой код и попытка реализовать IEnumerable:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Software> soft = new List<Software>()
            {new FreeSoftware("Adobe", "China"),
            new FreeSoftware("Illustration", "China"),
            new FreeSoftware("Vdobe", "China"),
            new FreeSoftware("Kaspersky", "China"),
            new SharewareSoftware("Dr.Web", "USA", new DateTime(2019, 03, 04), 0, 0, 6),
            new ProprietarySoftware("Avast", "Australia", new DateTime(2019, 02, 04), 0, 0, 6, 200)
        };
        Collection c = new Collection(soft);
        c.Search("Vdobe");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public abstract class Software : IComparable<Software>
{
    public string name_soft;
    public string made;

    public virtual bool can => true;
    public int CompareTo(Software soft)
    {
        Software p = soft as Software;

        if (p == null) throw new InvalidCastException();

        if (name_soft.First() > p.name_soft.First()) return 1;
        else if (name_soft.First() == p.name_soft.First()) return 0;
        else return -1;
    }
    public override string ToString()=>$"Название продукта - {name_soft} Страна производства - {made}";

    public void Search(List<Software> soft)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n ~Поиск софта который можно использовать~");
        foreach (var i in soft)
        {
            if (i.can)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i.ToString()}");
            }
        }
    }
}
public class FreeSoftware : Software
{
    public FreeSoftware(string name, string made)
    {
        base.name_soft = name;
        base.made = made;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
    public override bool can => base.can;
}
public class SharewareSoftware : Software
{
    public DateTime date_instal;
    private int year, month, day;
    public DateTime period_free;
    public SharewareSoftware(string name, string made, DateTime date_instal, int year, int month, int day)
    {
        base.name_soft = name;
        base.made = made;
        this.date_instal = date_instal;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        period_free = date_instal.AddDays(day).AddMonths(month).AddYears(year);
    }
    public override bool can => DateTime.Now < period_free;
    public override string ToString()=>$"{base.ToString()} Дата установки {date_instal.ToString("d")} Период бесплатного использования до {period_free.ToString("d")}";

}
public class ProprietarySoftware : Software
{
    public DateTime date_instal;
    public DateTime time_use;
    private int year, month, day;
    private double price;
    public ProprietarySoftware(string name, string made, DateTime date_instal, int year, int month, int day, double price)
    {
        base.name_soft = name;
        base.made = made;
        this.date_instal = date_instal;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        time_use = date_instal.AddDays(day).AddMonths(month).AddYears(year);
        this.price = price;
    }
    public override bool can => DateTime.Now < time_use;
    public override string ToString()=> $"{base.ToString()} Дата установки {date_instal.ToString("d")} Время использования до {time_use.ToString("d")} Цена {price}";

}
public class Collection : Software,IEnumerable<Software> { 
    private List<Software> soft;
    public Collection() : this(new List<Software>()) { }
    public Collection(List<Software> soft)
    {
        this.soft = soft;
    }
    public void Add_To_Collection(Software s)=>this.soft.Add(s);
    public void Remove_To_Collection(int a) =>this.soft.RemoveAt(a);
    public void Show_Collection() {
        foreach (var i in soft)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()=> $"Название коллекции {nameof(soft)} коллекция содержит {soft.Count} элементов";

    public void Sort()=> soft.Sort();

    public List<Software> Soft
    {
        get => soft;
    }
    public IEnumerable Search(string name)
    {
        foreach (var i in soft)
        {
            if (i.name_soft == name)
            {
                yield return i.ToString();
            }
        }

    }

    public IEnumerator<Software> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<Software>)soft).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<Software>)soft).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Я попытался реализовать, но что-то не так я сделал и не работает... Я так понял, что я не правильно понимаю, как реализовывать..
И вот ещё вопрос, что бы не создавать ещё одну тему: создать обобщённый метод с типом возврата List, который возвращает из коллекции лишь те объекты, тип которых указан в качестве обобщенного параметра метода, т. е. в качестве обобщённого параметра метода указывается тип дочернего класса, а из коллекции возвращаются только объекты указанного типа.

Comment: А в каком классе, простите, вы реализовываете `IEnumerable` ? Наличие метода `public IEnumerable Search(string name)` не является реализацией этого интерфейса.

Comment: @Bulson, простите. Я действовал по примеру найденному в интернете. По заданию создать итератор. Вроде все просто, но снова проблемы, как и были с IComparable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296961

Comment: Спасибо почитаю

Comment: @Bulson, да я понял, что не сделал, но всё же как же описать эти методы

Comment: о каких методах вы говорите?

Comment: @Bulson, `public IEnumerator<Software> GetEnumerator()` и 
   `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось так

```
public class SoftwareCollection : ICollection<ASoftware>
{
    private List<ASoftware> _softwares = new List<ASoftware>();

    #region Реализация ICollection<T>
    public int Count => _softwares.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add(ASoftware item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));

        _softwares.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _softwares.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(ASoftware item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));

        return _softwares.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(ASoftware[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        if (array == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));

        _softwares.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<ASoftware> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _softwares.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Remove(ASoftware item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));

        return _softwares.Remove(item);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _softwares.GetEnumerator();
    } 
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Сортировка
    /// </summary>
    public void Sort()
    {
        _softwares.Sort();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Получение коллекции нужного типа программ
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">тип программ в коллекции</typeparam>
    /// <param name="type">искомый тип программ</param>
    /// <returns>коллекции нужного типа программ</returns>
    public List<T> GetSoftwarByType<T>(Type type) where T : class
    {
        return _softwares.Where(s => s.GetType().Equals(type))
                         .Select(s => s as T)
                         .ToList();
    }
}
```

Работаем с этим так

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SoftwareCollection softwares = new SoftwareCollection
        {
            new FreeSoftware("FileZilla", "США"),
            new ProprietarySoftware("Adobe Photoshop", "США",
                    DateTime.Parse("12.12.2018"), TimeSpan.FromDays(360), 3600),
            new SharewareSoftware("WinRar", "Россия",
                    DateTime.Parse("12.12.2018"), TimeSpan.FromDays(90)),
            new ProprietarySoftware("ABBYY FineReader", "Россия",
                    DateTime.Parse("06.06.2017"), TimeSpan.FromDays(360), 2800),
            new FreeSoftware("FireFox Mozilla", "США")
        };

        //
        Console.WriteLine("=====До сортировки======");
        PrintCollection(softwares);
        Console.WriteLine("========================");

        Console.WriteLine("Для продолжения нажмите Ввод...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        softwares.Sort();

        Console.WriteLine("=====После сортировки======");
        PrintCollection(softwares);
        Console.WriteLine("========================");

        Console.WriteLine("Для продолжения нажмите Ввод...");
        Console.ReadLine();


        var freeSoftwares = softwares.GetSoftwarByType<FreeSoftware>(typeof(FreeSoftware));
        Console.WriteLine("=====Только Free=====");
        foreach (var item in freeSoftwares)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("========================");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void PrintCollection(SoftwareCollection softwares)
    {
        foreach (var software in softwares)
        {
            if (software is FreeSoftware)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((software as FreeSoftware));
            }
            else if (software is SharewareSoftware)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((software as SharewareSoftware));
            }
            else if (software is ProprietarySoftware)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((software as ProprietarySoftware));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(software);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Пример целиком можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/ExSoftware). Рекомендую посмотреть, т.к. там еще можете подсмотреть реализацию `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: Вух, неожиданный ответ) спасибо большое за помощь!!! Обязательно посмотрю!

Comment: да отличный пример, большое спасибо, очень хорошая реализация. Но как реализовать итератор для поиска элементов коллекции, удовлетворяющих заданному условию.

Comment: @Valera какому заданному условию? Вы же хотели метод, который бы возвращал коллекцию нужных типов, я его вам реализовал. Чем вас не устраивает реализация всевозможных условий с помощью `LINQ`?

Comment: в этом и проблема меня всё устраивает) Я так и сделал, но принимающий работу, сказал сделать через итератор. Допустим вывести по совпадение имени

Comment: Я понял, сейчас покумекаю...

Comment: @Bulcon, я просто не понимаю, как это вообще примерно сделать. Я понял как сделать что бы было понятно что перебирает, но через определенное условие у меня не работает. Я правильно понимаю, метод `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` является как сказать функцией которая вызывается в цикле `foreach`. Или я всё же не верно вычитал)?

Comment: Я дополнил пример (перегрузил метод), смотрите на гитхабе. Когда класс заявляет, что он реализует `IEnumerable` это значит, что он может через вызовы соотв. методов предоставить перечислитель (Enumerator), а он в свою явл.классом, кот. реализует `IEnumerator`, а значит имеет в своем составе метод `MoveNext()` его то и использует `foreach()` для передвижения по коллекции и имеет свойство `Current`, которое есть текущий элемент выбранный входе вызова `MoveNext()`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90949/discussion-between-valera-and-bulson).